# Arabic Wordnet for Synonyms in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nlp, arabic

I am using python 2.7, I am trying to get synonyms of Arabic words using Arabic WordNet

I downloaded both needed files:

AWNDatabaseManagement.py
upc_db.xml

Its working fine when I enter the word itself not using a variable

outputs In Backwalter form but I managed to translate them to arabic:

But the problem is that I want to loop on a set of words, but I get the following error

Comment: What was the point of the latest two edits? You have deleted most of the text and the question is completely useless now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the package that `AWNDatabaseManagement` comes from, but from reading your question it seems to be the case that  `wm.get_synsetids_from_word()` will return `None` when it can't find any results. (I don't know what "synsetids" are either.)

To avoid your error you can do this:

```
synsets = wn.get_synsetids_from_word(xxx) or []
```

This will assign the empty list `[]` to `synsets` only in the cases where the function returns `None`. Since an empty list is iterable, you will not get a typeerror when looping over it.

Comment: I haven't used ArabicWordNet, so I'm not familiar with how that library works. Have you read the documentation? In any case, this is a different issue than the one in you original question, which was core python stuff.